# Libraries for receiving Faxes for .NET platform

Tags: .net, api, fax

Can you recommend a library for .NET that can receive FAXes? Window Fax server is not enough - need to auto process and route the Fax once it is received based on the incoming Caller ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use a system which automatically routes faxes to email, and then make your .NET code just process emails? That would separate out your processing from the fax side of things. Aside from anything else, it would make it a great deal easier and cheaper to test.

It may not be the most efficient way of processing faxes, but it's practical.

Comment: I like your idea. Which changes the question to "What is a good Fax server to use"? Is the Windows Server 2008 fax server any good? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I've no idea on that front - it may well be worth asking a separate question.

Comment: I tried Windows Server 2008 Fax Services. It does a pretty good job of taking a Fax then allow routing it to Email (as TIF), or File folder. This allows processing. (Not sure on what API support it has)